# Create a wordpress post with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem, I can create a new post in my WordPress blog using PHP code:

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $leadTitle,
    'post_content' => $leadContent,
    'post_status' => $postStatus,
    'post_date' => $timeStamp,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'post_category' => array($categoryID),
    'tags_input' => array($tags)
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

My problem is that whenever post_content has HTML code in it, it does not get included with the post.

How can I include iframe tags within my `post_content`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [iframe shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/) instead.

```
[iframe src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/4qsGTXLnmKs” width=”100%” height=”500″]
```

> WordPress removes iframe html tags because of security reasons.
>   Iframe shortcode is the replacement of the iframe html tag and accepts the same params as iframe html tag does.

Comment: correction: it works. had to activate plugin...\\ Thanks!